Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException PHP 8.3.13 9.52.16 could not find driver select * from `users` where `email` = checker@example.com limit 1
I'm getting the error: could not find driver when calling
select * from users where email = checker@example.com limit 1

config(['app.timezone' => 'Asia/Manila']);

$input = $request->all();

$request->validate([
    'email' => ['required'],
    'password' => ['required'],
]);

if(auth()->attempt(array('email' => $input['email'], 'password' => $input['password']))) {
    switch (Auth::user()->role) {
        case 'admin':
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard.index');

        case 'student':
            return redirect()->route('student.dashboard.index');

        case 'checker':
            return redirect()->route('checker.dashboard.index');

        default:
            abort(403);
    }
} else {
    return redirect()->route('account.index');
}

I try in php.ini but nothing happens.

in your php.ini i hope you have enabled below extensions:
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=mysqli

if yes then only need to restart the server for Linux:
Apache:
sudo service apache2 restart

for ngnix
sudo service ngnix restart

and verify in terminal to check all enabled extension using php -m and verify above suggested extensions are enabled.
also verify your all .env variables are correct.
